# SimpleInjector Web API Attribute Filter Won't Return Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, asp.net-web-api2

I have followed this tutorial in order to inject dependencies into a custom filter via an method attribute.

https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98

Everything looks like its working, it hits the filter and calls the OnActionExecuting() method.

The problem I'm having is that when the user isn't authenticated, I want to return a custom response via context.Response, but it just carries on into the action result as-if the filter wasn't there.

Below are the various pieces of code taken from the above URL, plus my custom filter.

```
[Route("api/user/create")]
[AuthoriseRequest("Can_Create_User")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
```

.

```
public class AuthoriseRequest : Attribute
{
    public string PermissionName { get; set; }

    public AuthoriseRequest(string permissionName)
    {
        PermissionName = permissionName;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class AuthoriseRequestActionFilter : IActionFilter<AuthoriseRequest>
{ ... }
```

.

```
public void OnActionExecuting(AuthoriseRequest request, HttpActionContext context)
{

    var createUserRequest = (CreateUserRequest)context.ActionArguments["createUserRequest"];
    var validator = _requestValidator.Validate(createUserRequest);

    if (validator.IsValid())
    {
        var isAuthenticated =
            _authenticationManager.AuthenticateRequest(...);

        if (!isAuthenticated)
        {
            //THIS DOESN'T SET THE RESPONSE

            var unauthorisedRequestResponse = new APIResponse<string>(null, false, validator.ToString());
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.OK,
            unauthorisedRequestResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
public sealed class ActionFilterDispatcher : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly Func<Type, IEnumerable> container;

    public ActionFilterDispatcher(Func<Type, IEnumerable> container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor;
        var attributes = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<Attribute>(true)
            .Concat(descriptor.GetCustomAttributes<Attribute>(true));

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            Type filterType = typeof(IActionFilter<>).MakeGenericType(attribute.GetType());
            IEnumerable filters = this.container.Invoke(filterType);

            foreach (dynamic actionFilter in filters)
            {
                actionFilter.OnActionExecuting((dynamic)attribute, context);
            }
        }

        return continuation();
    }

    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return true; } }
}
```

.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters, Container container)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ActionFilterDispatcher(container.GetAllInstances));
    container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IActionFilter<>), typeof(IActionFilter<>).Assembly);
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Thanks.